# How to limit the up-directory search for file info

Tags: find-file

As Emacs opens a file it does all sorts of useful things including walking up the directory tree for more information (repos etc).  I'm in a situation where I need to curtail that climb.  Is there a mechanism for this or other work around?

Comment: Can you elaborate? For example, just what directory-walking are you referring to in `find-file`?

Comment: In my observation, many of these special handlings don't take place in find-file-literally. E.g. git repos is not detected, auto-mode-alist does not take effect etc. Does find-file-literally not work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

There's `locate-dominating-stop-dir-regexp`:

```
Regexp of directory names which stop the search in ‘locate-dominating-file’.
Any directory whose name matches this regexp will be treated like
a kind of root directory by ‘locate-dominating-file’ which will stop its search
when it bumps into it.
The default regexp prevents fruitless and time-consuming attempts to find
special files in directories in which filenames are interpreted as hostnames,
or mount points potentially requiring authentication as a different user.
```

Comment: By no means am I a regex pro but I can't even get a near-static value to stop the directory search.(custom-set-variables
 '(locate-dominating-stop-dir-regexp "\\`/uufs/chpc\\.utah\\.edu/home/camp-group1\\'")) does not work (nor does adding a forward slash after "group1"

Comment: As emacs walks up the dir stack looking for multiple possible version control systems etc I get a three second delay (strace) for each as it crosses an automount point at /uufs/chpc.utah.edu/home.  I suppose I could remove the list of things to look for (I'm only using one vcs) but that would still leave one 3 second delay at least. (Much better than the 20-30 sec. currently)

Comment: the path should read "...edu/common/home/" which is what I'm using in my attempts

Comment: I have tested my expression (using the same test seen in locate-dominating-file) and it returns true (non-nil) when the directory is ONLY my intended stopper and nil otherwise, so I'm starting to doubt that this mechanism is used under find-file. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried *with* or *without* a trailing slash?  When `locate-dominating-stop-dir-regexp` is passed to `string-match`, the file name used is as returned by `file-name-directory` so it has a trailing slash.

Comment: Yes with and without trailing forward slash (and /?) but from your input I'll add it explicitly.  string-match does return nil comparing my regex to anything other than my intended "root" and zero for my intended root

Comment: Maybe the problem doesn't come from `locate-dominating-file`, then?  I suggest you start debugging this with `M-x trace-function RET locate-dominating-file RET`.  You can also `M-x elp-instrument-function RET locate-dominating-file RET` and look at `M-x elp-resullts` to see how much time is spent inside it.

Comment: Is it possible that the "(defvar locate-dominating-stop-dir-regexp ...)" in files.el is not really overridden by my "(custom-set-variables(locate-dominating-stop-dir-regexp (purecopy( "\\`/uufs/chpc.utah.edu/common/home/camp-group1/"\\'")) Ctrl-Hv certainly shows my custom value. And this test work (returns 0).(setq tfile "/uufs/chpc.utah.edu/common/home/camp-group1/")
(string-match locate-dominating-stop-dir-regexp tfile)
and nil with any other value for tfile

Comment: trace-function shows: 1 -> locate-dominating-file: file="/uufs/chpc.utah.edu/common/home/camp-group1/bin/segmentViewGT.awk" name=".dir-locals.el"
1 <- locate-dominating-file: nil  repeated for .hg, .svn, git et al

Comment: elp-instrument-function shows: function=locate-dominating-file  calls=7           total-time=20.386204558  avg-time=2.9123149368 which is what I'm seeing (time-wise) using strace.  I get there by C-x C-f on a file on the camp-group1 partition.  Emacs tools don't report for each dir assessed in locate-dominating-file as strace does.  Only the test of home (one up from camp-group1) >95% of the delay

Comment: I have managed to step through the workings of locate-dominating-file. I supplied a custom stop regex and that was used but only the first time through.  The second time through (testing for a subsequent dominating file) the built-in value for the stop regex was used.  Is this an emacs bug in custom-set-variables.  I added my stop regex to that list manually.

Comment: So "defvar" is largely immutable.  I can only see rebuilding files.el with "defcustom locate-dominating-stop-dir-regexp" (or maybe defvar with nil default) as way to getting a site specific stop regex.

Comment: `defvar` is definitely not immutable.   Something confuses you, but this is not a good place to track it down.  Better do it in a discussion forum (e.g. gnu.emacs.help).

Comment: For completeness, I submitted a bug against "vc-ignore-dir-regexp" which resets the default value of locate-dominating-file-regexp, over-writing what ever one assigns.

Comment: @rjs: just a nitpick: `vc-ignore-dir-regexp` does not *reset* the value, it only temporarily overrides it.

Comment: not temporarily enough ;).  IIRC It overrides any current value with the default value, then uses that default (plus what it wants to look for) and that lands me in trouble.  I also feel the default is a bit outdated?

Comment: FWIW `"\\`/uufs/chpc.utah.edu/common/home/camp-group1/"\\'"` should be `"\\\`/uufs/chpc.utah.edu/common/home/camp-group1/\"\\'"` (although I think stackexchange was responsible for the first of those differences, and I suspect that `"` near the end isn't supposed to be there at all, and may have just been a typo in the comment).